# Fundamental CAPM questions

Tags: capm

A couple questions about the CAPM model:

1. If I only know the riskfree rate and expected market return, how do I solve for $\beta$ ?
2. Given the stock's variance, how do I solve the percentage of it that is due to market risk and how do I interpret this?

I searched this question through google, but I cannot find reasonable answer. Please help me! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Because you have CAPM therefore the following holds:

> $$r_i = r_f + \beta_i (r_M - r_f) + \epsilon_i$$

where $r_i$ is the expected return of stock $i$, $r_f$ is the risk free return and $r_M$ is the expected market return, and $\epsilon$ is an idiosyncratic return adjustment or an error.

Now if you take the $\text{Var}[\cdot]$ operator over the equation above you should have.

$$
\begin{split}
\text{Var}[r_i] & =\text{Var} \left [ r_f + \beta_i (r_M - r_f) + \epsilon_i \right ] \\
& = \text{Var}[r_f] + \beta_i^2  \text{Var} [r_M - r_f] + \text{Var} [\epsilon_i] \\
& = 0 +  \beta_i^2 \text{Var} [r_M] + \text{Var} [\epsilon_i] \\
& = \beta_i^2 \text{Var} [r_M] + \text{Var} [\epsilon_i]
\end{split}
$$

**This is the relation you're looking for, it's a decomposition of variance.** (Notice there's no covariance terms by the assumption of CAPM). It tells you that the variance of your stock return is two-fold. First, it comes from the systematic risk where you bear from market risk, namely $\beta_i^2 \text{Var} [r_M]$. Second, each stock has its idiosyncratic risk, which is $\text{Var} [\epsilon_i]$.

Now in this problem you have $\beta_i$, $\text{Var} [r_M]$ and $\text{Var}[r_i]$ given. What percentage of this variance is due to market risk you ask? That's just

$$\frac{\beta_i^2 \text{Var} [r_M]}{\text{Var}[r_i]}$$

Now if you want to be even more convenient. You can re-write the above relation as

$$\frac{\beta_i^2 \text{Var} [r_M]}{\text{Var}[r_i]} = \frac{\text{Cov}^2[r_i,r_M]}{\text{Var} [r_M] \text{Var} [r_i]} = \rho_i^2$$

This is because

$$\beta_i = \frac{\text{Cov}[r_i,r_M]}{\text{Var} [r_M]}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

write the return of stock B as

$R_B=\beta R_M +  e$

where $e$ is uncorrelated to $R_M.$ Find a formula for its variance and substitute all the terms you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand correctly the first question but if so: you have to know the stock return also. In this case the answer is trivial: $\beta = (r_i - r_f) / (r_m - r_f)$

About the second question:

analytically speaking the answer of Kenneth Chen is correct but let me add that this representation is valid in *Single Index Model* case and not necessarily in CAPM. In CAPM setting, strictly speaking, the is no way to answer for you question because CAPM say not enough about second moments. See here [Difference between CAPM and single index model](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31401/difference-between-capm-and-single-index-model/44137#44137)