# Are commodities a real assets or a physical assets?

Tags: asset

In CFA Level Reading 45

> Commodities include precious metals, energy products, industrial
>   metals, and agricultural products. Real assets are tangible properties
>   such as real estate, airplanes, or machinery. Securities, currencies,
>   and contracts are classified as financial assets whereas commodities
>   and real assets are classified as physical assets.

So commodities is not a real asset? Commodities and real assets are part of physical assets?

Comment: The distinction is as I understand it between capital (airplanes, real estate) and commodities. Both are physical (pumpkins and bridges), but real assets are capital assets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to Quantitative Finance in particular.

Comment: do whatever you want...

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21417/fundamental-capm-questions

Mine q is off topic, but this basic rudimentary question about CAPM is "quantitative finance"? Oh please.